# Is it possible to use a String instead of a variable name in Java

Tags: java, string, variables

I've created 3 variables

radio1
radio2
radio3

is it possible to use a for loop and from a String called "radio" to add the counter in the end in order to get the variable?

for instance something like this

```
for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
    if(("radio" + i).method())
          do something
```

thanks in advance

Comment: No, check out arrays. Reflection is technically an answer to this... just like "build a language with stdlib that does it that way" is technically an answer to "function X does Y, I want it to do Z".

Comment: In context to his question, Reflection is not an answer.

Comment: @Saket: agrees with Johan: reflection is not the solution to the overall problem and is adding additional danger without benefit when simple arrays or hashmaps would solve this easily.

Comment: In Java what's important is not so much the variable name, which is almost non-existent when the code is running, but rather having a reference to your objects. An array or map will do this nicely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a Radio object and use arrays instead:

```
Radio[] radios = new Radio[] {radio1, radio2, radio3};
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    if(radios[i].method())
          do something
```

If you want to access variable by forming their names, you can also use [Java's reflection API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html). But it is an expensive operation and is not advisable in general.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you want to use a [Dictionary](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Dictionary.html) or similar data structure, which lets you store objects indexed by, for example, a string.

EDIT

As several people noted, `HashMap` is a more modern and better alternative.

Comment: Please note that `Dictionary` and `Hashtable` are deprected for quite some time. Please do _NOT_ recommend these for new code or for new coders.

Comment: Agreed - [Map](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) implementations should be used instead.

Comment: @A.H. While I would recommend HashMap myself, Hashtable is *not* deprecated and has been retrofitted with generics. (Dictionary is obsolete ;-)

Comment: `Hashtable` is not `@deprecated` but it is 'deprecated'. The forced synchronization overhead, some duplicate methods and the good replacement `HashMap` justify this more than enough.
Also note, that both classes has been retrofitted to generics, therefore this is not the only one criteria for deprecation without `@deprecated`.

Comment: Sorry, C# on the brain as of late!  Let me correct the entry.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using an `array` so you can easily iterate over all of them.

You could also play with Lists if you do not know how many items there wil be.

Answer (score 0):

The most convenient way is to use an intermediate array like this:

```
Radio radio1, radio2, radio3;
for(Radio radio: Arrays.asList(radio1, radio2, radio3))
    if( radio.method() )
        doSomething();
```

The `java.util.Arrays` is provided by the JDK.

This works. But please think about it, how many times you really want three separate `Radio` instances vs. how many times you are not interested in one of them but in all of them. In the later case put the three instances into a `Collection` or into an array right from the start and forget about the three individual instances.